# RESTful api routes for nested resources with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Let's say I have a nested ressources as follow:

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books
end
```

Given I have hooked up Devise to my API to authenticate users.

Let's say an author authenticates himself, should I provide a routes such as `/books` or should I stick to the `/authors/:author_id/books` route?

My logic behind is that, since I can determine who logged in, providing `/books` makes sense and `/authors/:author_id/books` seems overkill and more suitable to an admin's api...

Can someone shed some light as far as what would be the best (more sustainable) approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to use /books then you are limited to a lot of the functionality in rails and would have to write extra code just to pull data from the author.

I like the author **/authors/:author_id/books** approach because you have control over the author_id param. Say you were to use a gem such as [friendly_id](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id) then your url would look something like **/authors/jsmith** and there on jsmith page is where you could list his books without going to **/authors/jsmith/books**

If you're using devise, protect each user page by calling the current_user method in the index action and by setting the current_user id in your controller create action rather than the form hidden field. Use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorization.

Comment: I agree, it seems more within the convention to stick to the nested url for nested resources...

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer `/books` way.
My arguments:

1. In that case logic in your controller will be something like this:

   ```
   books = current_author.books.all()
   ```

   and its totally save you from any kind of evil users who want to take access to private information (cause in this case the only way to take access to books is log in as author - so security concentrated in 1 place)
2. It's much more comfortable to author to have list of his books in `/books` section
3. Cause in /books route there is no user id, it's predict user from replacing user id in url. Some people like to do that and see what will happen. And i think you dont want them to do that

So my vote is for `/books`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer versioning for my API and using nesting where it is required. If for example books are **always** scoped by a `author_id` it should be nested, otherwise it should not be.

A versioned route would look like:

```
`/api/v1/books/:id`
```

Where the `BooksController` is in a map under `/controllers/api/v1` and its class declaration looks like:

```
module Api::V1
  class BooksController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

and `routes.rb` looks like

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do


  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :authors
      resources :books
    end
  end

end
```

Versioning is nice for the client implementations of the API. You can add new functions and refactor without breaking support.

Comment: thanks for the hint but that doesn't really address my questions as far as nested resources are concerned...